# How to apply functions on elements of list

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to apply a function on the following list and want to get of `{n,{x,y}}` the solution `x^2-n*y^2`
It can be done by:

```
 t3 = {{{11, {3, 1}}, {12, {3, 1}}}, {{11, {10, 3}}, {12, {7, 
          2}}}, {{11, {63, 19}}, {12, {45, 13}}}, {{11, {199, 
          60}}, {12, {97, 28}}}, {{11, {1257, 379}}, {12, {627, 181}}}};
    tn = t3[[All, All, 1]];
    tx = t3[[All, All, 2, 1]];
    ty = t3[[All, All, 2, 2]];

    tx^2 - tn*ty^2
```

resulting in

```
{{-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}}
```

What would be a more elegant way to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Apply[{1, -#} . #2^2 &, t3, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}}
> ```

Also

```
☺ = {1, -#}. #2^2 & @@@ # & /@ # &;
☺ @ t3
```

> ```
> {{-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}}
> ```

and

```
Map[{1, - First@#} .  Last[#]^2 &, t3, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}}
> ```

and

```
ReplaceAll[{n_?NumericQ, {x_, y_}} :> x^2 - n y^2] @ t3
```

> ```
> {{-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}}
> ```

Comment: writing ```{1, - #1}``` is more readable maybe?

Comment: @youyou, good point.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this:

`Partition[#, 2]& @ (#[[2, 1]]^2 - #[[1]]*#[[2, 2]]^2 & /@ Flatten[t3, 1])`

`{{-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}, {1, 1}, {-2, -3}}`